# how to make jenkins declarative pipeline waitForWebhook without consuming jenkins executor?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

We have a Jenkins declarative pipeline which, after deploying our product on a cloud vm, needs to run some product tests on it. Tests are implemented as a separate job on another jenkins and tests will be run by main pipeline by triggering remote job on 2nd jenkins using parameterized remote trigger plugin [parameterized remote trigger plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/Parameterized-Remote-Trigger/).

While this plugin works great, when using option blockBuildUntilComplete it blocks for remote job to finish but doesn't release the jenkins executor. Since tests can take a lot of time to complete(upto 2 days), all this time executor will be blocked just waiting for another job to complete. When setting blockBuildUntilComplete as false it returns a job handle which can be used to fetch build status and result etc. Example [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameterized-remote-trigger-plugin/blob/master/README_PipelineConfiguration.md#non-blocking-usage):

```
while( !handle.isFinished() ) {
    echo 'Current Status: ' + handle.getBuildStatus().toString();
    sleep 5
    handle.updateBuildStatus()
}
```

But this still keeps consuming the executor, so we still have the same problem.
Based on comments in the [article](http://cpitman.github.io/jenkins/cicd/2017/03/31/waiting-for-remote-systems-in-a-jenkins-pipeline-now-easier.html#.XrKzQmgzZPY), we tried with waitForWebhook, but even when waiting for webhook it still keeps using the executor.

Based on [article](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2018/04/09/whats-in-declarative/) we tried with input, and we observed that it wasn't using executor when you have input block in stage and none agent for pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("test"){
            input {
                message "Should we continue?"
            }
            agent any
            steps {
                script{
                    echo "hello"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so input block does what we want to do with waitForWebhook, at least as far as not consuming an executor while waiting. 
What our original idea was to have waitForWebhook inside a timeout surrounded by try catch surrounded by a while loop waiting for remote job to finish :

```
 while(!handle.isFinished()){
        try{
            timeout(1) {
                data = waitForWebhook hook
            } 
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.info("timeout occurred")
        }
        handle.updateBuildStatus()
    }
```

This way we could avoid using executor for long period of time and also benefit from job handle returned by plugin. But we cannot find a way to do this with the input step. input doesn't use executor only when it's separate block inside stage, but it uses one if inside steps or steps->script. So we cannot use try catch, cannot check handle status andcannot loop on it. Is there a way to do this?

Even if waitForWebhook works like input is working we could use that.
Our main pipeline runs on a jenkins inside corporate network and test jenkins runs on cloud and cannot communicate in with our corp jenkins. so when using waitForWebhook, we would publish a message on a message pipeline which a consumer will read, fetch webhook url from db corresponding to job and post on it. We were hoping avoid this with our solution of using while and try-catch.